# Add localstorage link as a image src

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hello I have a local storage link that needs to be displayed as a img src. If the local storage link is google.com I want it to be displayed as a img src

code so far

```
<body>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
  <img src="" id="photo" /> //this is the img element
  <script>
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
      var dataImage = localStorage.getItem('imgData');
      document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name"); //localstorage 
    } else {
      document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

I know this question is confusing but this is the best I could describe.

Comment: you mean setting the img src if an image is stored inside localstorage?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the image `src` attribute to the value you get from local storage. (Assuming that's a path to an image)

You would not want to set the `innerHTML` of an `img` tag. Instead, use another element to display text.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<img src="" id="photo" /> //this is the img element
<div id="msg"></div>
<script>
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var dataImage = localStorage.getItem('imgData');
    var imageName = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var imageEl = document.getElementById("photo");
    imageEl.src = imageName 
  } else {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Comment: You should not use `.innerHTML` when the string doesn't contain any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Is there a non-javascript, maybe data-src way of doing it?